# Decision tree classification of satellite image in R

Tags: r, image-processing, decision-tree, satellite-image

I want to classify satellite image in R using RWeka classifier, J48. I have a CSV file with the classes required, and raster data loaded in R. I am able to make the tree, however, I am not able to use the same tree to classify my satellite image.

Here's how it goes.

```
inputfile=read.csv("E://R/Trial/naini.CSV")
m1 <- J48(Class~B1+B2+B3+B4+B5+B7, data = inputfile)
if(require("party", quietly = TRUE)) plot(m1)
raster<- brick("merge.tif")
plotRGB(raster, 4, 3, 2, stretch="hist")
```

And then I am attempting to use the tree generated to classify my satellite image, but I keep getting errors.

```
predict (test_new, J48, filename=out_classify, progress='text',format='GTiff', datatype='FLT4S', type='response', overwrite=TRUE)
Error in trim(filename) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'trim': Error: object 'out_classify' not found
```

And if I change the arguments, this is what I get. I am not sure how to proceed from this point forward.

```
predict (J48, test_new, filename=out_classify, progress='text',format='GTiff', datatype='FLT4S', type='response', overwrite=TRUE)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('R_Weka_classifier_interface', 'R_Weka_interface')"
```

I am new to R, so I might take a while to decipher your answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO!, have you defined the object, `out_classify` in  `filename=out_classify`, apparently the function `trim` is not able to find the object `Error: object 'out_classify' not found`.

Comment: Okay. I wasn't aware we were supposed to do that. Anyhow, I did as you said, but still not working.

Comment: `predict (raster, J48, filename=x, progress='text',format='GTiff', datatype='FLT4S', type='response', overwrite=TRUE)
Error in .local(x, ...) : only NA values found`

Comment: The `filename` parameter expects a character input, such as `filename='testfile'`, The correct syntax is `predict (object=test_new,model= J48, filename='out_classify', progress='text',format='GTiff', datatype='FLT4S', type='response', overwrite=TRUE)` Check out this link on more examples [link] (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/predict)

Comment: Yeah, I did work around that, but it seems that RandomForest is available to predict fitted model to raster data, and not J48 classifier.

Comment: `Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('R_Weka_classifier_interface', 'R_Weka_interface')`